# Realtek NICs won't operate at 1000BaseT

Tags: realtek

I have tried a Realtek 8139 and Realtek 8111 NIC on my 12.04 Ubuntu desktop machine.  Neither will operate at 1000BaseT when I try to force it with ethtool.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue and unfortunately, no one but you and I seem to recognize this is the problem behind the "slow wired connection" problems in all the blogs.

I have not found a solution other than plugging it into a 100Mb switch instead of a gigabit switch and running at 100 full duplex.

You can add to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

**EDIT:** Found a solution!!!

You can download and install an updated driver from [this link](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168%3Cbr%3ERTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E%3Cbr%3ERTL8168E/RTL8111F)

I am now (finally) at gigabit.